How do I get vba to find text and then bold it?
Currently I have a userform with a combobox where once an option is chosen a document variable is set based on what option is chosen. Once the docvariable is set I want to only bold a part of the text. The docvariable is LSBV, the combobox is LSB.

Private oVars As Variables

Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables


If LSB.Value = "Lump Sum" Then
    oVars("LSBV") = "The Company Lump Sum price to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST. Additional work or variations will be carried out at the following rates:"
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Company Lump Sum price to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST."
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
ElseIf LSB.Value = "Budget" Then
    oVars("LSBV") = "The Company budget estimate to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST. The works will be carried out on the following schedule of rates:"
    Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Company budget estimate to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST."
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
End If


Currently it bolds "The Company Lump Sum price to" or "The Company budget estimate to". It shouldn't bold the initial "The" and it misses a lot of what should be bolded. How would I fix it to bold what should be bolded?






Presumably, you're using a DOCVARIABLE field, so why aren't you adding the bold formatting to that directly instead of trying to bold it after the fact via VBA? Additionally, I see no reason for 'The' to be included in the variable - that can be in the document body already.

Are you able to bold things in the DOCVARIABLE field without bolding eveything because i dont want everything bolded. You are right about there being no reason to include "The", thanks for making me realising that.

Whatever approach you use, you can't reliably bold only part of the content of a field. As soon as anything happens to cause the field display to refresh (e.g. a print preview or printing), the entire field is liable to revert to its default state. Accordingly, for what you've described you will need to have outputs to be bolded/not bolded in different variables, with a field for each. It's a simple matter to use a Charformat switch to apply the bold formatting to the desired fields.

If I understand your question correctly, you simply need to exclude the first word from the Word search.
Microsoft documentation:

Find.Execute method (Word)

    Dim sTxt As String
    Debug.Print LSB.Value, (LSB.Value = "Lump Sum") ' debugging code
    If LSB.Value = "Lump Sum" Then
        sTxt = "The Company Lump Sum price to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST. Additional work or variations will be carried out at the following rates:"
    ElseIf LSB.Value = "Budget" Then
        sTxt = "The Company budget estimate to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST. The works will be carried out on the following schedule of rates:"
    End If
    oVars("LSBV") = sTxt

    Dim iLoc As Long: iLoc = InStr(1, sTxt, " ")
    If iLoc > 0 Then ' remove the first word
        sTxt = Mid(sTxt, iLoc + 1)
    End If

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True        
        .Text = sTxt
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With


Sub Test()
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = "The Company Lump Sum price to complete the above scope is $xxx + GST. Additional work or variations will be carried out at the following rates:"
    
    Dim iLoc As Long: iLoc = InStr(1, sTxt, " ")
    If iLoc > 0 Then ' remove the first word
        sTxt = Mid(sTxt, iLoc + 1)
    End If

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Text = sTxt
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub



I've copied this code over and it sets the text correctly but it doesn't bold it. Was I supposed to add or change something to the code once i copied it?

Please share a snapshot of your doc.

i've added snapshots to the edit of my question @taller

Pls add debugging code (the 2nd line in the updated script) to validate the value of LSB.  btw, do you need to use oVars("LSBV") in your script?

I added the debugging code line, what change does that make to the code also? I would not need to use oVars("LSBV") if it is easier to do otherwise

Check the output of deugging code in VBE Immediate Window.

Lump Sum is True is the output when i choose Lump Sum. Budget is false is the output when i choose Budget

@ZacJ I'm unsure about the code within the userform. I've uploaded a test script along with a screenshot for reference.
